# Jenkings on DCOS - Marathon-plugin missing after install

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dcos

I added the Marathon plugin to Jenkins through the Jenkins management Web UI.  It showed up as a list of available plugins to install.  I also downloaded the HPI and added the plugin manually.  In both cases, the Marathon option doesn't show up in my pipeline config.  I'm following the steps here: https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/tutorials/jenkins/#building-a-docker-image-and-deploying-it-to-marathon

Comment: Are you actually on DC/OS 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Use version mesosphere/jenkins:3.0.1-2.32.2 in combination with persisting your Jenkins data on NFS. Installation and updates of plugins works for me with this combination.

You should consider missing functionality in older versions of Jenkins in DC/OS as described in this thread: https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-jenkins-service/issues/105

Do you use a NFS share to persist your Jenkins data? In my experience you can not use DC/OS Jenkins properly without persisting Jenkins' data.